# Find Replace in Contact Notes Macro

Tags: vba, email, outlook, contacts

I am trying to build a macro to delete a series of emails scattered throughout a MS Outlook Contact's note field.  Here is what I have so far, when it executes, it appears nothing visible happens.  Thx for any feedback.
Emails look like `<name@xyz.com>`

```
Sub OutlookDeleteTextBetween()
Dim olInspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim olDocument As Word.Document
Dim olSelection As Word.Selection

Set olInspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
Set olDocument = olInspector.WordEditor
Set olSelection = olDocument.Application.Selection
olSelection.WholeStory

With olSelection.Find
      .Text = "\<*\>"
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> delete a series of emails scattered throughout a MS Outlook Contact's note field

Try to `Save` the mail item after you did some changes. Outlook may not propagate changes until you save the item or re-open the window.

If you need to find attached mail items, they are stored as attachments in Outlook items. It seems to you need to check out the `Attachments` collection and use the [Attachments.Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.remove?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm177)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) method which removes an object from the collection. For example:

```
Sub RemoveAttachmentBeforeForwarding()  
 Dim myinspector As Outlook.Inspector  
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem  
 Dim myattachments As Outlook.Attachments 

 Set myinspector = Application.ActiveInspector  
 If Not TypeName(myinspector) = "Nothing" Then  
   Set myItem = myinspector.CurrentItem.Forward  
   Set myattachments = myItem.Attachments  
   While myattachments.Count > 0  
     myattachments.Remove 1  
   Wend  
   myItem.Display  
   myItem.Recipients.Add "Eugene Astafiev"  
   myItem.Send  
 Else  
   MsgBox "There is no active inspector."  
 End If  
End Sub
```

Comment: The question was a bit unclear, I am trying to delete a series of email addresses, (not emails) basically, search for any text between '<name.xyz.com>' and replace with ""

Comment: Try to `Save` the mail item after you did some changes. Outlook may not propagate changes until you save the item or re-open the window.